# Weblogic installer reads from incorrect file

Tags: java, debugging, weblogic12c

I am trying to install [Weblogic 12c](http://onlineappsdba.com/index.php/2011/12/10/oracle-weblogic-12c-1211-is-now-available-to-download/).

I placed the Weblogic jar files in my C drive.

To compile and run the jar file, I typed the following command

```
java -jar fmw_12.2.1.0.0_wls_quick.jar
```

I have ensured that

**1) Command prompt is run in administration mode**

**2) Environmental variable JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79**

However I get the following error

```
This installer must be executed using JDK but C:\Program Files\Java\jre7 is not a valid JDK
```

It appears that the installer is reading from **C:\Program Files\Java\jre7** instead of **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79**

How do i change the installer setting to correct the changes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you still use jre java

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -jar fmw_12.2.1.0.0_wls_quick.jar
```

Comment: I get the following error : "C:\Program is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: add a quote to it `"%JAVA_HOME%\java" -jar fmw_12.2.1.0.0_wls_quick.jar`

Comment: i added double quotes as shown but I still get the same error

Comment: sorry I think it should be `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -jar fmw_12.2.1.0.0_wls_quick.jar`